# Optimizing Group Spending

Tags: finance, economics

I have always thought that groups of individuals that spend more money(as opposed to save) have more money in the long run. My reasoning is that if a particular group spends money, then each dollar that one person spends is being used by more individuals, and thus one physical dollar, might have a value of $10/day. (spent 10 times a day)

While if a group does not spend money, then one physical dollar may only have a value of $0.1/day. (spent once in ten days)

Is there any logic in my thought process?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This idea is studied in economics, where it is called the [velocity of money](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_of_money).

You should be careful that not all transactions create value in the same way. If you pay me $\$1$ to erase your blackboard, this is equivalent to and creates the same value as if you sell me the dirty blackboard for $\$100$ and then buy it back for $\$101$ once it is clean. However, the total size of the transactions may look different, $\$1$ versus $\$201$.